# Magento 2.4.1: One or more of your dotdigital cron tasks have errors: ddg_automation_customer_subscriber_guest_sync,

Tags: magento2.4.1

At the top of Magento admin page, below are the messages displayed. I'm not sure what these mean and how to fix them all. Please help me understand this.

One or more of your dotdigital cron tasks have errors: ddg_automation_customer_subscriber_guest_sync, ddg_automation_status, ddg_automation_reviews_and_wishlist, ddg_automation_catalog_sync, ddg_automation_importer, ddg_automation_campaign, ddg_automation_order_sync, ddg_automation_monitor, ddg_automation_abandonedcarts. Please go to Cron Tasks to review.

Comment: Did you ever figure this error out? Its started on one of my Magento 2 sites since updating it.

Comment: I think we disabled the module.

Comment: I'm not sure disabling the module is the solution. I'm using latest magento and it's happening to me too. It's filed as bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32951

Comment: I responded on the issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/32951#issuecomment-836825460

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue this past week, but today it seems to have resolved and no longer displaying those errors.

I can't say for sure what resolved it, but yesterday I ran all the following from the console.

```
rm -rf var/di/* ;
rm -rf var/generation/* ;
rm -rf var/cache/* ;
rm -rf var/log/* ;
rm -rf var/page_cache/* ;
rm -rf var/session/* ;
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* ;
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*;

bin/magento setup:upgrade;
bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade;
bin/magento setup:di:compile;
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
bin/magento indexer:reindex;
bin/magento cache:clean;
bin/magento cache:flush;
```

Side note: Check what version of PHP your console is running and that its the same as the web server and cron scheduler. If you did the recent Magento update with php 7.4, but your scheduled task run under php 7.2 or lower, it will fail for that too.

Comment: Chris, did you find this error recur? I see it again in the admin.

Comment: @PKTG I haven't seen it no, lets not jinx it! Did you do any updates on composer, or did it just reappear by its self?

Comment: We might have done composer update a while ago.